# How to use c# webservice in php?

Tags: c#, php, web-services, dll, windows-server-2012

I have a c# web service and one dll file, I create a php project and now need to use this web service in my project

I want to run my project on windows server 2012

How I can include the dll file in my project and use web service methods?

my c# sample code:

```
PMIService TestService = new PMIService();
PersonInfoVO Person = new PersonInfoVO();
Person = TestService.GetPersonByNationalCode(TB_NationalCode.Text);
MessageBox.Show(Person.FirstName + " " + Person.LastName);
```

Comment: can you highlight the exact problem? Is this a PHP problem or a C# one?

Comment: I my naivity, I would think you need to make an .exe out of your DLL and then use exec() within PHP to access the output of that .exe. However, this will only work on a 'command prompt' interface basis, that is: texts. A more basic approach would be to rebuild PHP with your DLL included. But I'm not an expert, wait to see what other people say.